# Org mode To Do's: completed tasks statistics cookie for items more than one level down

Tags: org-mode, todo

I am working on a project with several steps, each of which has sub-steps; each sub-step has sub-steps as well. The steps and sub-steps are headings; the sub-sub-steps are To Do items. I would like to have the steps' statistics cookie reflect whether the sub-steps are completed. It remains at 0/0, even if the sub-steps show the level of completion of the To-Do items in the sub-sub-steps. Minimal working example, below.

I suspect the key can be found somewhere in the [documentation on sub-tasks](https://orgmode.org/manual/Breaking-Down-Tasks.html), but I haven't been able to make this work yet.

Thank you for helping out! This is my first StackExchange question.

```
** Step 2 EDA (SQL) [0/0]
*** Number of rides 15-16 Nov [3/3] 
- [X] Find number of rides for each company 15 - 16 November
- [X] Name the resulting field trips_amount and print it along with the
  company_name field.
- [X] Sort the results by the trips_amount field in descending order.
*** Yellow and Blue cabs [0/3]
- [ ] Find the number of rides for every taxi company whose name contains the
  words "Yellow" or "Blue" for November 1-7, 2017.
- [ ] Name the resulting variable trips_amount.
- [ ] Group the results by the company_name field.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have the second level statistics cookies be influenced by the fourth level checkboxes: you can only have them influenced by the TODO/DONE status of the third-level headlines. In other words, you are going to have to do something like this, adding TODO states to your third-level headlines:

```
** Step 2 EDA (SQL) [1/2]
*** DONE Number of rides 15-16 Nov [3/3] 
    CLOSED: [2020-06-04 Thu 23:02]
    :PROPERTIES:
    :VISIBILITY: folded
    :END:
    - [X] Find number of rides for each company 15 - 16 November
    - [X] Name the resulting field trips_amount and print it along with the
    company_name field.
    - [X] Sort the results by the trips_amount field in descending order.
*** TODO Yellow and Blue cabs [1/3]
    :PROPERTIES:
    :VISIBILITY: folded
    :END:
    - [X] Find the number of rides for every taxi company whose name contains the
    words "Yellow" or "Blue" for November 1-7, 2017.
    - [ ] Name the resulting variable trips_amount.
    - [ ] Group the results by the company_name field.
```

Note that the second-level headline statistics cookie does not care about the checkboxes two levels down; it only cares about the TODO states one level down.

But having to navigate to a headline in order to change its TODO state after all of its checkboxes are checked is a pain. Fortunately, there are ways to do that automatically. In fact, I wrote some code to do that a long time ago and [it's still available at the Org mode Worg site](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html#mark-done-when-all-checkboxes-checked) - and, miracle of miracles, I just tried it and it still works! I add it here to make the answer self-contained but you should read the linked Org Hacks entry for some caveats:

```el
(eval-after-load 'org-list
  '(add-hook 'org-checkbox-statistics-hook (function ndk/checkbox-list-complete)))

(defun ndk/checkbox-list-complete ()
  (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading t)
    (when (re-search-forward "\\[\\([0-9]*%\\)\\]\\|\\[\\([0-9]*\\)/\\([0-9]*\\)\\]"
                             (line-end-position) t)
      (org-todo (if (if (match-end 1)
                        (equal (match-string 1) "100%")
                      (and (> (match-end 2) (match-beginning 2))
                           (equal (match-string 2) (match-string 3))))
                    ;; All done - do the state change.
                    'done
                  'todo)))))
```

One thing I should point out: in order for the hook to be run, you need to change the checkbox state either by clicking on it or with `C-c C-c` from the keyboard. If you modify the state of the checkbox manually by changing the `X` to a space or vice versa will not update the state of the statistics cookies until *something* runs the hook.Other than that, just add the code to your initialization file and you should be all set.

P.S. Thanks to @Stefan for cleaning up the code.

Comment: Yup, works exactly as advertised. Yay! Thank you for this code and for answering my question. I had to make sure to change the second- and third-level headings to TODO items. Thanks again!