# Uncheck checkboxes on completing recurring task

Tags: org-mode

I would like any checked checkboxes under a TODO heading to be unchecked when I mark it as DONE, **if** the heading is a habit and/or reoccurring. The usecase is to have a list of checkboxes under a heading to keep track of what minor issues has been completed, and then to have it cleared for next time.

I imagine the `style` property would be useful, but it's the general behavior I am looking for, exactly how it is achieved matter less.

Comment: Part of [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58915/org-mode-to-dos-completed-tasks-statistics-cookie-for-items-more-than-one-leve/58917#58917) might help.

Comment: ... in the sense of "No, it does not do what you want but it might provide a useful idea".